# Swift: How to make UITextField react when its text isn't set by a user?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have two textfields and editing one of them results in filling the other one:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        if textField == self.mgdlTextField {

            if let text = textField.text {
                if let value = Double(text) {
                    self.mmolTextField.text = "\(value / 38.6)"
                    return
                }
            }
            self.mmolTextField.text = ""


        } else {

            if let text = textField.text {
                if let value = Double(text) {
                    self.mgdlTextField.text = "\(value * 38.6)"
                    return
                }
            }
            self.mgdlTextField.text = ""
        }

    }

    return true
}
```

The problem occurs when I want to retrieve the value of the self-filled text field, I add target:

```
cell.mmolTextField.addTarget(self, action: "updateLDL1:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents .EditingChanged)
```

The action above is not called, I suppose this might be the result of the fact that this was not noticed as a control event.
I tried changing .EditingChanged into .AllEvents but this is not the solution.

How would you approach such issue? Maybe NSNotifications may come in handy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set the delegate of the 'mmolTextField'?

Comment: self.mmolTextField.delegate = self inside awakeFromNib() method since it is located on UITableViewCell

Comment: Is this line with the `addTarget` inside of your `awakeFromNib()` method as well? Or is it somewhere else that it is definitely getting called?

Comment: No, addTarget is in the viewController inside cellForARowAtIndexPath method

Comment: You may try adding the target and action for the textField inside of the cell itself. Then you can use a protocol or typealias to notify the tableViewController when the textField is updated and pass along the contents of the textField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to trigger the event yourself:

```
self.mmolTextField.sendActionsForControlEvents(.EditingChanged)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you assigned a delegate to your UITextField.
The delegate has methods textFieldDidBeginEditing: and textFieldDidEndEditing: that should help you here. No need to implement other touch controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Key Value coding:

```
var textField: UITextField!
var observer: NSObject!

func textFieldObserverTest() {
    if textField == nil {
        textField = UITextField()
        observer = TextFieldObserver()
        textField.addObserver(observer, forKeyPath: "text", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    }
    textField.text = "Hello World"
    textField.text = "Goodbye World"
    textField.text = "Its all over"
}

class TextFieldObserver : NSObject {
    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    print("\(keyPath!) changed to \(change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey])")
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Try using `UIControlEventValueChanged`

this is for Obj-C find equivalent for swift.

Comment: ValueChanged does not work for textFields from what I know